# Error in R: column type remains 'character' even after applying as.numeric

Tags: type-conversion

new programmer here. Have spent an hour trying to figure this error out. I'm sure I'm missing something, I just don't know what.

**update: found a workaround, new question at the bottom**

I loaded a BLS spreadsheet, and saw that all of the columns are characters, when I need them to be numeric. I applied as.numeric, but when I check the class type, it remains character.

```
> state2<-read_excel("Spreadsheets/state_M2022_dl.xlsx") 
> str(state2)                                                                                                           
tibble [37,569 × 32] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ AREA        : chr [1:37569] "01" "01" "01" "01" ...
 $ AREA_TITLE  : chr [1:37569] "Alabama" "Alabama" "Alabama" "Alabama" ...
 $ AREA_TYPE   : chr [1:37569] "2" "2" "2" "2" ...
 $ PRIM_STATE  : chr [1:37569] "AL" "AL" "AL" "AL" ...
```

When I try as.numeric and check the class:

```
> as.numeric(state2$OWN_CODE)
   [1] 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235
  [24] 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235 1235

> class(state2$OWN_CODE)
[1] "character"
```

I see a few posts with a similar error, but they involve dataframes created in R, not imported spreadsheets.

**update:**

The following workaround seems to work -- is there a shorter/more efficient way of doing this than writing this out for every variable?

> state2$H_PCT25<-as.numeric(state2$H_PCT25)

Warning message:
NAs introduced by coercion

> class(state2$H_PCT25)
> [1] "numeric"